# HTML / CSS / JS line drawing

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, drawing

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to draw thousands of lines on a page.

I have a database that contains every single point that I'd like to draw and I can pull these into a python list of coordinates that looks like: [[0,0],[200,100],[400,250]]. This list includes about 2000 points. And I'd like to connect each of these points together with a line segment forming 1 big line. Each segment may need to be a different colour

On every page, I'd like to draw 2-3 of these big lines (so there will be about 2000-6000 points per page)

My 2 questions are:

1. What is the most efficient way to draw this many lines without slowing down the browser?
2. Is there a way to make the resulting image/canvas zoomable so users can zoom in on specific sections of this line and navigate around?

Im currently using some test code like this, but is there a more efficient way to do this:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400"
style="border:1px solid #ffffff;"></canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(200,100);
ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(200,100);
ctx.lineTo(400,250);
ctx.strokeStyle = '#6b44cc';
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();

</script>
```

Comment: Why not run a performance test on a subset: http://jsperf.com/html-vs-svg-vs-canvas/5

Comment: For efficiency, I would most likely not try one of the plugins (such as D3) and rely on Canvas, as you have here, or SVG.  And, if the performance tests above are any indicator, you're on the right path.

Comment: I did a small test with 200k diffrent colored lines and canvas draws then pretty fast, so speed should not be an issue but with 2000 lines per page you are only going to see randomness (don't think zooming will matter that much, will test that later) http://jsfiddle.net/dqkksbz6/2/

Answer (score 2):

Compiling these points to an SVG file seems like the most efficient option. If I understand your question correctly, you already have a database of points you'd like to draw. This means that there is no need to generate this image on the fly.

I would guess a precompiled SVG image would load a lot faster than lines drawn on a canvas. Canvas may be faster at generating images on the fly, but if you can generate your image before hand, this will save you a lot of time in the browser. SVG would also be zoomable so I think this best fits your criteria.

Here's an example of a library you could use to [zoom and pan your SVG](http://ariutta.github.io/svg-pan-zoom/demo/inline.html)

**EDIT:**

I created a large SVG image with 100000 lines (similar to dwana's canvas one here:  jsfiddle.net/dqkksbz6/2) and found that my guess was wrong. As MarkE points out, a huge amount of DOM nodes does have a significant impact on browser performance. **SVG is actually slower**. Using a canvas is a lot faster and doesn't break the browser the way a huge SVG does.

Still, my original point still stands about generating the image before it's requested. MarkE's comment is very helpful and maybe there's something in that. You could generate a PNG which then switches out to a small SVG of the relevant area once a certain zoom level is reached. This would be quite a lot of work to put together, but I can't think of a better way to optimise for both speed and quality.

Comment: It's tempting to use SVG when resizing is involved because vector-based SVG will zoom without pixelization. I do have a worry though...the questioner plans on having 6000 points plus 6000 lines connecting those points = 12000 multi-colored svg children! I suspect adding that much content to the DOM will crush performance.  Perhaps a hybrid approach: (1) present a high PPI img element when zoomed out. (2) enlarge the img until it pixelizes (maybe 2-5X zoom) and then (3) use SVG to present a much smaller set of zoomed points/lines.